# How to restrict number of signs in Entry widgets with Tkinter

Tags: python, text, tkinter, limit, restrict

Hello i tried to do that in loop, but can't understand why only last created one is the only one restricted? I'd like to limit the 12 created widgets in loop to 4 signs. Can someone help me? :3

PS. Sorry if something uncleared, i ask question here for the first time.

```
from tkinter import *
import trace
import random


class Plansza:

    def __init__(self, master):


        self.frame = Frame(master, bg="brown")
        self.frame.pack()
        self.tab = [random.randint(1, 6),random.randint(1, 6),random.randint(1, 6),random.randint(1, 6)]
        print(self.tab)
        print(len(self.tab))
        self.max_len = 4

        self.wynik = StringVar()
        self.wynik.set(self.tab)

        self.goal = Entry(self.frame, width=6, font=50, fg="purple", justify=CENTER, textvariable=self.wynik, show="*")
        self.goal.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=30, pady=30)

        self.pokaz = Button(self.frame, text = "Pokaż", command=self.show)
        self.pokaz.grid(row=0, column=2)
        self.wiersz=1
        print(self.wynik.get())
        self.var = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
        self.iter = 0
        self.map()

        self.sprawdz = Button(self.frame, text = "Sprawdź")
        self.sprawdz.grid(row=self.wiersz+1, column=1, padx=50, pady=50)



    def on_write(self, *arg):
        s = self.var[self.iter].get()
        if len(s) > self.max_len:
            self.var[self.iter].set(s[:self.max_len])


    def show(self):
        self.goal.config(show="")

    def map(self):
        self.var[self.iter]=StringVar()
        self.var[self.iter].trace_variable("w", self.on_write)

        self.pole_na_odp = Entry(self.frame, width=6, font=50, fg="purple", justify=CENTER, textvariable=self.var[self.iter])
        self.pole_na_odp.grid(row=self.wiersz, column=1, padx=20, pady=20)
        self.wiersz+=1
        self.var.append([])
        self.iter+=1
        if(self.wiersz<12):
            self.map()

root = Tk()
b = Plansza(root)


root.mainloop()
```

[EDIT] I did a list but now I've got another error:
Whenever i wanna type something in my Entry widgets i got en error like this:

```
s = self.var[self.iter].get()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'
```

And there are no more restrict number of sings even in last Entry widget.

Comment: You are applying your limit to `self.var` - a single variable, no matter how many Entries you create.  (Each one's var overwrites the previous one's.)  You would need to maintain a *list* of vars.

Comment: I don't see how your question title refers to the text or the code. What do you mean with "restrict signs", where is the loop you are talking about, and what is the code supposed to do anyway?

Comment: Oh my bad, I did it in loop before, but now I just do it by recursive.
I create 12 entry widgets and i want to restrict number of enterable sings into them to 4.

Answer (score 0):

(Answer to the question in your edit.)

In this line

```
s = self.var[self.iter].get()
```

it looks like you are trying to use `get()` to return an element of `self.var`. That is not how lists work. I'm pretty sure what you want is

```
s = self.var[self.iter]
```

Comment: *I* know that he is calling `get()` on an integer, but I'm not sure that *he* knows that. It is clear that he is overgeneralizing `get()` as a way to get R-values. It's not clear whether he is trying to apply it to the list element, or to the list itself.

Comment: I just have no idea how to deal with it :/